# Merge CommandFields ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, commandfield

This is the GridView :

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdProduct" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="sdsProducts" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdProduct_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="1000px" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="Black">
<AlternatingRowStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" />
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Nom" SortExpression="Name" />
    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" CancelImageUrl="~/Images/dataG/cancel.png" DeleteImageUrl="~/Images/dataG/delete.png" EditImageUrl="~/Images/dataG/edit.png" InsertImageUrl="~/Images/dataG/insert.png" ShowEditButton="True" UpdateImageUrl="~/Images/dataG/update.png" />
    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" CancelImageUrl="~/Images/dataG/cancel.png" DeleteImageUrl="~/Images/dataG/delete.png" EditImageUrl="~/Images/dataG/edit.png" InsertImageUrl="~/Images/dataG/insert.png" ShowDeleteButton="True" UpdateImageUrl="~/Images/dataG/update.png" />
    </Columns>
<FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="White" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
<RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
<SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />
```

It gives me this result :

```
--------------------------------
|ID | Name |         |          |
--------------------------------
|  1 | x     | Edit   | Delete|
|  2 | y     | Edit   | Delete|
|  3 | z     | Edit   | Delete|
--------------------------------
```

But i want it to be like this :

```
--------------------------------
|ID | Name |       Action      |
--------------------------------
|  1 | x     | Edit     Delete|
|  2 | y     | Edit     Delete|
|  3 | z     | Edit     Delete|
--------------------------------
```

Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use one TemplateField with a HeaderText = "Action" to do this, instead of the two CommandFields. In the TemplateField, you can add the buttons as regular  elements.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for responding, I'm a beginner so i don't quit understand what you meant, is this what you said :

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" CancelImageUrl="~/Images/dataG/cancel.png" DeleteImageUrl="~/Images/dataG/delete.png" ... />
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" CancelImageUrl="~/Images/dataG/cancel.png" DeleteImageUrl="~/Images/dataG/delete.png"... />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

Comment: Not exactly, what I meant is:                                               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action"> 
 <ItemTemplate> 
  <asp:Button ... /> 
  <asp:Button ... /> 
 </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>